# Tricky selection of elements based on their position

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to make a list of some elements from a 4D array with dimensions 4x4x4x4. I need to select the elements based on their position in the following way: name an element e(x,y,z,w); I need all the elements where x≥y and z≥w. This basically excludes all the upper triangular part of each submatrix and all the submatrices in the upper triangular part of the tensor. The array in question is this one:

```
b={{{{12, 0, 0, 0}, {-18 Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, {12 Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0}, {-6, 
0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}}}, {{{-18 Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, {84, 0, 0, 0}, {-48 Sqrt[6], 0, 0,
 0}, {54 Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 60, 0, 
0}, {0, -90, 0, 0}, {0, 18 Sqrt[10], 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}}, {{{12 Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 
0}, {-48 Sqrt[6], 0, 0, 0}, {276, 0, 0, 0}, {-186 Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 
0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -90, 0, 0}, {0, 240, 0, 
0}, {0, -90 Sqrt[10], 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
168, 0}, {0, 0, -84 Sqrt[6], 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}}, {{{-6, 0, 0, 0}, {54 Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 
0}, {-186 Sqrt[3], 0, 0, 0}, {648, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
18 Sqrt[10], 0, 0}, {0, -90 Sqrt[10], 0, 0}, {0, 600, 0, 0}}, {{0,
 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -84 Sqrt[6], 0}, {0, 0, 504, 
0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 360}}}}
```

I tried in many ways but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `MapIndexed` for level `{-1}` in combination with `Reap/Sow`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your definition:

> This basically excludes all the upper triangular part of each submatrix and all the submatrices in the upper triangular part of the tensor.

```
With[{lt = LowerTriangularize, ca = ConstantArray},
  Pick[b, # * ca[#, {4, 4}] & @ lt @ ca[1, {4, 4}], 1]
] ~Flatten~ 3
```

Comment: I think this is what Im going to use, because very soon I will have to do it for a 20x20x20x20 array and this seems pretty quick.

Answer (score 6):

Do these give what you want?

```
rv1[b_] := 
  Module[{tag}, 
   SparseArray[{x_, y_, z_, w_} /; x >= y && z >= w :> 
      b[[x, y, z, w]], Dimensions@b, tag]["NonzeroValues"]];

rv2[b_] := 
  Extract[b, 
   Cases[Range@4~Tuples~{4}, {x_, y_, z_, w_} /; x >= y && z >= w]];

rv3[b_] := 
  Extract[b, 
   Table[{x, y, z, w}, {y, 4}, {x, y, 4}, {w, 4}, {z, w, 4}]~Flatten~
    3];

rv4[b_] := 
  With[{extract = 
     With[{parts = Table[{x, y}, {y, 4}, {x, y, 4}]~Flatten~1}, 
      Extract[#, parts] &]}, Flatten[extract /@ extract@b, 1]];

(*This is @Spawn1701D's suggestion*)
spawn[b_] := 
 Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#1, #2[[1]] >= #2[[2]] && #2[[3]] >= #2[[4]]] &, 
    b, {4}], True][[-1, 1]]

(* from @MrWizard *)
wiz1[b_] := 
 With[{lt = LowerTriangularize, ca = ConstantArray}, 
   Pick[b, #*ca[#, {4, 4}] &@lt@ca[1, {4, 4}], 1]]~Flatten~3
```

Let's check the results

```
contenders = {rv1, rv2, rv3, rv4, spawn, wiz1};

Equal @@ Sort /@ Through@contenders[b]
(* True *)
```

Some timings

```
Through@(Composition @@@ 
    Tuples@{{First}, {AbsoluteTiming}, contenders})[b]

(* {0.019003, 0., 0.00100, 0., 0.002001, 0.} *)
```

Using this function `TimingAverage` that I took from somewhere sometime and never looked into

```
TimingAverage[expr_, time_ : 1.`] := 
 Module[{t = Timing[expr;][[1]], tries = 1}, 
     While[t < time, tries *= 2;
        t = Timing[Do[expr, {tries}];][[1]];];
    t/tries]
```

You get

```
Through@(Composition @@@ 
    Tuples@{{TimingAverage}, contenders})[b]

(* {0.0185251, 0.000716020, 0.000154249, 0.0000656987, 0.00237658, 0.000148536} *)
```

So, from top to bottom, `rv4`, `wiz1`, `rv3`, `rv2`, `spawn`, `rv1`

Comment: Thanks.  I'm curious, do you personally use `TimingAverage` over the `timeAvg` function (originally from Timo) I've posted many times willfully, or was this an ad hoc function?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard because I never even looked into any of them to see pros and cons and I have it packaged up from a long time ago. If you think the other one is better, edit it in and I'll trust you and change my packaging ;)

Comment: No need; it does the same thing I believe, only I chose a multiplier of five.

Comment: Could you add timings for the method I just posted, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard already done. +1 btw

Comment: Well you can try just `Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#1,#2[[1]]>=#2[[2]]&&#2[[3]]>=#2[[4]]]&, b, {-1}], True]` but I don't think will be much faster though.

Comment: @Spawn1701D, but it's way neater, edited. I'll insist with level `{4}` because he has square roots

Comment: @Rojo with `{-1}` will access the base elements no matter what the structure is and this in combination with a generic constraint on the indexes can make it more general.

Comment: @Spawn1701D if you give a working solution with `{-1}` I'll edit it in

Answer (score 2):

A flexible solution :

```
Reap[ReplacePart[
      b,
      ({x_, y_, z_, w_} /; x >= y && z >= w) :> Sow[Extract[b, {x, y, z, w}]]
    ];][[2, 1]]
```

So far I know, `ReplacePart[]` is the only instruction that accepts a pattern of indexes as argument. That's the reason why I use `ReplacePart[]`. In fact we don't care of the result of the replacements.

This solution is very flexible but not efficient in terms of quickness and memory occupation.

Answer (score 2):

Two `Pick`'s; first picks out matrices, second elements:

```
With[{s = ConstantArray[True, {3, 3}] // UpperTriangularize},
  Map[
   Pick[#, s] &,
   Pick[m, s], {-3}]] // Flatten
```

`Pick` also works with `SparseArray` objects, so:

```
Pick[b, SparseArray[{x_, y_, z_, w_} /; x >= y && z >= w -> True,
   Dimensions@b]] // Flatten
```

Comment: I like this. +1